# "Error in model.frame.default(data = train, formula = cost ~ .) : variable lengths differ", but all variables are length 76?

Tags: r

I'm modeling burrito prices in San Diego to determine whether some burritos are over/under priced (according to the model). I'm attempting to use regsubsets() to determine the best linear model, using the BIC, on a data frame of 76 observations of 14 variables. However, I keep getting an error saying that variable lengths differ, and thus a linear model doesn't work.

I've tried rounding all the observations in the data frame to one decimal place, I've used the length() function on each variable in the data frame to make sure they're all the same length, and before I made the model I used na.omit() on the data frame to make sure no NAs were present. By the way, the original dataset can be found here: https://www.kaggle.com/srcole/burritos-in-san-diego. I cleaned it up a bit in Excel first, removing all the categorical variables that appeared after the "overall" column.

```r
    burritos <- read.csv("/Users/Jack/Desktop/R/STOR 565 R Projects/Burritos.csv")

    burritos <- burritos[ ,-c(1,2,5)]

    burritos <- na.exclude(burritos)

    burritos <- round(burritos, 1)

    library(leaps)

    library(MASS)

    yelp <- burritos$Yelp

    google <- burritos$Google

    cost <- burritos$Cost

    hunger <- burritos$Hunger

    tortilla <- burritos$Tortilla

    temp <- burritos$Temp

    meat <- burritos$Meat

    filling <- burritos$Meat.filling

    uniformity <- burritos$Uniformity

    salsa <- burritos$Salsa

    synergy <- burritos$Synergy

    wrap <- burritos$Wrap

    overall <- burritos$overall

    variable <- sample(1:nrow(burritos), 50)

    train <- burritos[variable, ]

    test <- burritos[-variable, ]

    null <- lm(cost ~ 1, data = train)

    full <- regsubsets(cost ~ ., data = train) #This is where error occurs
```

Comment: Try `na.rm` instead of `na.omit` and check to see if they are still the same length

Comment: I actually fixed it by using full <- regsubsets(train$cost ~ ., data = train). That being said, I'll play around with na.rm too and see how it goes.